# Error disabling Parental Control on my child's Samsung Galaxy S10

Tags: samsung, parental-control, google-family-link

I can't disable Parental control or add my own account on my son's Samsung Galaxy S10. The only option available since my son is only 9 is to remove or delete the account.

As per updated Google Play services version 23.24.14 2023, they recommend the device for factory settings.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

If it was easy to remove Parental Controls, the kids would do it.  If you can not remember the PIN or if you are seeing an error then **Factory Reset** is the only way.

You will see some sites say that deleting data from Google Play Services App will clear Parental Controls. You can try it, but I don't think it will work.  Its no big deal, I am sure your child will soon download every thing that will lose.

Answer (score 0):

To stop supervision of your kid's phone, you might wanna try this (from his device):
[Google For Families Help - Add & manage supervision on a current Google Account](https://support.google.com/families/answer/9055704?hl=en#zippy=%2Cset-up-supervision-from-your-childs-android-device%2Cstop-supervision-with-a-parents-device%2Cstop-supervision-with-your-childs-device)

> Stop supervision with your child's device
>
> > If you added supervision to your child's existing Google Account, your child can also turn off supervision themselves. If your child turns off supervision without your permission, you'll be notified and their supervised Android devices will lock temporarily.
> > **Important:** To stop supervision on your child’s device, it must have Android 7.0 or higher.
> >
> > 1. On your child's device, open Settings .
> >
> >    - On Android versions 8.1 (O) and later, tap **Digital Wellbeing & parental controls**.
> >    - On other Android versions, tap **Google > Parental controls**.
> > 2. At the top right, tap More > **Stop supervision**.
> > 3. To verify you are a parent, sign in or use your Parent Access Code.
> > 4. To turn off supervision, follow the on-screen instructions."

---

As for adding another account, why not create a new profile by allowing multi user then sign in your own account in that new profile - Search for 'user' from phone settings app.

Comment: I think they have tried that already